# Add Z Values to Point Coordinates

Tags: qgis, geojson

I am tracing routes from a road segments layer with the goal graphing the elevation profile of the route in JavaScript with GeoJSON. This is my "real world" hobby project to get familiar with GIS and JavaScript. Open to any suggestions.

After picking a route, from the processing toolbox I "Explode lines" then "Segmentize by maximum distance". I would like to export this with the Z coordinates, the closest thing I have found so far is "Join attributes from closest" where I select a layer created from a CSV with a grid of XYZ data. The result is close but I would like to have the Z value in the coordinates rather than the attributes.

All my data is from https://maps.canada.ca/czs/index-en.html

Comment: Download raster elevation data for your area of interest: https://dwtkns.com/srtm/ Then use `Drape (set Z value from raster)` algorithm in processing toolbox.

Comment: @BenW Thank you this works! I was confused why elevation should be difficult to work with in a geography application but raster elevation data seems to be the key. The link was a great help.